# How update UI when AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate() finish?

Tags: android

When open Activity I start long (10 sek) process. This process create list of 10 items. And finish after 10 sec. As result the list show (UI update) AFTER 10 seconds.

But I need to show every item right after it create. So, first item must show after 1 second.

So I create AsyncTask for this:

```
onCreate() {
 BackgroundTask  backgroundTask  = new BackgroundTask ();
   backgroundTask.execute(newsDetailsList);
}

    private class BackgroundTask  extends AsyncTask<List<NewsDetails>, NewsDetails, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<NewsDetails>... newsDetailsList) {
            List<NewsDetails> passedList = newsDetailsList[0];
            for (NewsDetails newsDetails : passedList) {
                publishProgress(newsDetails);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final NewsDetails... passedNewsDetails) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(passedNewsDetails);
           final NewsDetails newsDetails = passedNewsDetails[0];
          // here create UI for new items newsDetails
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
}
```

But UI is updated AFTER **onPostExecute()** finish (after 10 SECONDS). But I need to update UI after every finish (10 times) method **onProgressUpdate()**.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the notifyDataSetChanged

```
      @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(final NewsDetails... passedNewsDetails) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(passedNewsDetails);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Basicly, you refresh the ListView each time progress updated

Comment: I am not use ListView for list. I use embedded Linearlayouts to create Ui. So list of 10 items is a 10 Linearlayouts in ONE main Linearlayouts. As result I can not call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

create a new class:

```
public interface NewsDetailsInterface{
void receiveData(Object object);
}
```

then change your ASyncTask to abstract and implement the interface:

```
private abstract class BackgroundTask  extends AsyncTask<List<NewsDetails>,
NewsDetails, Void> implements NewsDetailsInterface{

public abstract receiveData(Object object);

//.. the rest of your task below ..
```

then wherever you are instantiating the ASyncTask, you'll need to recreate it to look like this:

```
BackgroundTask  backgroundTask  = new BackgroundTask (){
            @Override
            public void receiveData(Object object) {
                 //do something with the object, like create a new list item
            }
       };
```

now, you can call receiveData every 1 second with your doInBackground, everytime it is called, your interface will do something with that data immediately:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<NewsDetails>... newsDetailsList) {
        List<NewsDetails> passedList = newsDetailsList[0];
        for (NewsDetails newsDetails : passedList) {
            receiveData(newsDetails);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I use WebView that can't be create on background. I think this is a problem